# Finding the inverse of a matrix using elementary transformations

Tags: matrices, inverse, transformation

> $$A:=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 &  2    &  3
> \\\\ 1  &  3   &  5
> \\\\ 1   &  5  &  12
> \end{pmatrix}$$

Using $A = A I$ where left hand side is transformed into an identity matrix using elementary row and column operations and the same operations are made on $I$ on the right hand side which will result in $I = A A'$ where $A'$ is inverse of the matrix $A$ .  Is

$$A'=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &  -2    &  1
\\\\ -1  &  3   &  -3
\\\\ \frac{2}{3}   &  \frac{7}{3}   &  3
\end{pmatrix}\ ?$$